# Can't delete UEFI variable - no space left / operation not permitted

Tags: uefi, systemd-boot

I'm installing Arch Linux on a new machine, and I've gotten to the point where I need to configure the bootloader, however this is failing:

```
# bootctl install
Failed to create EFI Boot variable entry: No space left on device
```

Looking at the variables, I can see the problem:

```
# ls -la /sys/firmware/efi/efivars --sort=size --reverse
...
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    6 May 17 17:50 BootCurrent-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   12 May 17 17:50 334-71db7b7e-4165-48fa-ac9d-f9af4cefc534
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   36 May 17 17:50 2151678337-417acee0-6fa9-4a82-99d7-f9b1dd271e48
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  124 May 17 17:50 Boot0000-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2.3K May 17 17:50 2151678336-417acee0-6fa9-4a82-99d7-f9b1dd271e48
```

There is a very large file there taking up all the space.  There is a folder with the same name in `/boot` with a date of a few minutes ago, so apparently one of my failed `bootctl` attempts somehow created this enormous UEFI variable taking up all the space.  Removing this would appear to free up enough space to set the boot variables properly, but unfortunately this is not possible:

```
# rm 2151678336-417acee0-6fa9-4a82-99d7-f9b1dd271e48 
rm: cannot remove '2151678336-417acee0-6fa9-4a82-99d7-f9b1dd271e48': Operation not permitted
```

Even though I'm doing this as root, I can't remove the file.  I have been able to remove *some* of the other variables, but I can't remove any variable I want, and I can't add any at all, even after removing everything I can.

How can I remove this bogus UEFI variable to free up NVRAM space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so it turns out that to prevent accidental deletion of UEFI variables, only whitelisted ones are allowed to be deleted by default.  Others are marked as immutable which prevents them from being deleted by accident:

```
# lsattr
-------------------- ./BootCurrent-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c
----i--------------- ./334-71db7b7e-4165-48fa-ac9d-f9af4cefc534
----i--------------- ./2151678337-417acee0-6fa9-4a82-99d7-f9b1dd271e48
-------------------- ./Boot0000-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c
----i--------------- ./2151678336-417acee0-6fa9-4a82-99d7-f9b1dd271e48
```

This was done so that running `rm -rf /` won't wipe out unknown UEFI variables which has been found to cause some buggy firmware implementations to fail to boot.  (The specs say systems must boot fine with all UEFI vars removed, but some machines aren't compliant and can be bricked this way.)

The immutable attribute has to be removed first:

```
# chattr -i 2151678336-417acee0-6fa9-4a82-99d7-f9b1dd271e48
```

Which still didn't allow me to remove or overwrite the variable, but it did allow me to remove a different one.  I still couldn't add any new variables, but after a reboot Linux picked up the extra space and `bootctl install` finally succeeded.

Comparing against another identical machine, it turns out this massive UEFI variable is in fact meant to be there!  So you just end up with a tiny amount of free storage space for boot variables on these machines with Linux (because apparently Linux will refuse to write any UEFI vars if there is less than 50% free space).

EDIT: You can also boot the kernel with the `efi_no_storage_paranoia` parameter to disable this limit and get access to the full EFI storage area, as long as you're sure your firmware isn't one of the early ones that fail to boot once the free EFI variable space drops below 50%.